# How can I increase the expiry time of 'appSession' cookie getting set after OIDC login in 'express-oidc-connect' package?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, openid-connect, auth0

Currently the expiry time of `**appSession**` cookie that gets set in the browser once the user successfully logs in is of about 24 hours. I want to increase it to 30 days. I tried passing `maxAge` in login method. But still nothing works.

```
res.oidc.login({
        authorizationParams: {
          response_type: 'code',
          scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
          client_id: 'client_id',
          redirect_uri: 'url',
          state: '123456789',
          //max_age: 'number'
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `rollingDuration` in the config object when initializing OIDC. Docs for `rollingDuration` [here](https://auth0.github.io/express-openid-connect/interfaces/SessionConfigParams.html#rollingDuration). This is if you want a rolling session that renews itself. If you want the session to expire after a specific amount of time, then use `absoluteDuration`.

```
import { auth } from 'express-openid-connect';

const config = {
  ...
  session: {
    rollingDuration: 2592000 // 30 days, in seconds,
  },
};

export const ExpressOIDC = auth(config);
```